# Empty pdf file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file, pdf

i am trying to send a file via html client side, and create it in the server side on a folder called files.

So basicly i already have a pdf file on my folder, but it is empty and i don't know why.

**This is how i send it via html:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h2>Select a file</h2>
      <input name="curriculum" id="inputVal" type="file">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

**and on the server i have the upload route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var defaultFolder = '../files/';
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.files) {
    return res.status(400).send("No Files were uploaded");
  }
  console.log(__dirname);
  var curriculum = req.files.curriculum;
  fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '../files', curriculum.name), curriculum.data.toString(), (err) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.send("can't write file");
    }
      return res.send("data writted");
  });
});
```

any help???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's inside `curriculum.data.toString()`?

Comment: Look into using multer. It makes uploading files in node.js a lot easier. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: this:  

00000000  47 49 46 38 39 61 32 00  32 00 f7 00 00 96 8c 73  |GIF89a2.2.�....s|
00000010  66 5e 45 c6 bb 9f 7b 72  5a 47 47 47 8a 81 65 ca  |f^Eƻ.{rZGGG..e�|